# Trying to make an IP scanner, problems with output

Tags: bash, awk

Ok, so I'm trying to make an IP scanner that outputs ONLY the ip addresses of hosts on my network, and open ports. This is what I have so far...

```
< #!/bin/bash

nmap 192.168.1.1-254> scan.txt
cat scan.txt | grep "report" | cut -d " " -f 5 >
```

and my output....

```
FIOS_Quantum_Gateway.fios-router.home
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.103
MT1.fios-router.home
192.168.1.154
```

I've tried multiple cut and awk combinations, but I can't get it to work....any ideas?

Comment: That looks like you're getting what you want, but you don't want DNS resolution? Use the `-n` flag to `nmap`.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have the following nmap output in a file called "my_nmap_file.txt"

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-12-07 15:19 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.020s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
23/tcp    open  telnet
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
3333/tcp  open  dec-notes
5555/tcp  open  freeciv
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
MAC Address: C4:3D:C7:8F:03:19 (Netgear)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.025s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.2 are closed
MAC Address: 58:C3:8B:63:52:96 (Samsung Electronics)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.8
Host is up (0.058s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.8 are closed
MAC Address: F0:27:65:79:1A:B7 (Murata Manufactuaring Co.)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.6
Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.6 are closed
```

You can try the command line

```
cat 'my_nmap_file.txt'|grep "Nmap scan report for *" |grep -o  -E '[0-9.]+'|sed '1 s#.*#Your Gateway: &#'
```

This will match find the following lines like below and take its ip address

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
```

Output

```
Your Gateway: 192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.6
```

Note: I added a little sentence called `'Your Gateway:'` for the first line

I notice you also want open ports matching the ip address.if you can provide  thethe messages given by nmap for open ports. Probably we can find that pattern too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`grep -e "report +[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\"`

this will look for `report` followed by one or more spaces followed by four . separated sets of numbers only.  There are more elegant ways to do this but not as easy to see what it is doing.